# simple parsing XML using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the following xml file which I'm trying to read with JQuery

```
<albums startAlbumNo="1">


    <album id="1">

        <author>author1</author>

        <image>images/2010-1-web-ready.jpg</image>

        <caption>caption1</caption>

        <tracks>
            <item id="31">
                <title>title1</title>
                <artist>artist1</artist>
                <song>content/stories/ChristmasStory.mp3</song>
            </item>
            <item id="32">
                <title>title2</title>
                <artist>artist2</artist>
                <song>content/stories/ChristmasStory2.mp3</song>
            </item>
        </tracks>

    </album>

    //similiar albums below
    <album>....</album>
    <album>....</album>
    <album>....</album>

</albums>
```

And I have the following JQuery to read it

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){    //run when page loads

var buttonNames = new Array();
var foo;

function parse(document){    //extract song locations from mp3gallery.xml based upon album

  buttonNames[0] = $(document).find('album[id="1"]').find("tracks").find("title").eq(0).text(); //this works

   $(document).find("album").each(function(){  //this does not
     alert('1');  //never runs
     foo = $(this).find('image').text();
    }
  alert(foo);  //never runs


   changeButtonNames(); 
}

  $.ajax({
    url: 'mp3gallery/xml/mp3gallery.xml', // name of file you want to parse
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,  //on success calls the "parse" function
    error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}

  });


  function changeButtonNames(){ //has to be run last

      document.getElementById('btn1').innerHTML = buttonNames[0]; 
  }

});
```

the

```js
$(document).find('album[id="1"]').find("tracks").find("title").eq(0).text();
```

runs fine, however my .each loop does nothing.

I have been looking at numerous examples for a while with no success. I am probably missing something obvious. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what the implications are of passing in a variable named `document`, maybe try changing that to something like `xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an error in your code

make it

```
$(document).find("album").each(function(){  //this does not
     alert('1');  //never runs
     foo = $(this).find('image').text();
});
```

Comment: After hours of looking at it I forgot the closing ) lol. Thanks so much